# Detect each object points in Autocad (.DXF or DWG) exported xml file

Tags: xml-parsing, autocad

I have Autocad files .DXF or .DWG, I export them as XML files from Autocad.
The files for example are for a house plan, with garden and pool...
I need to be able to upload the xml file on a web application, then read each object, like the pool only, how can I detect where are the points of the pool in the xml file, using Javascript.

Was the question clear or you need more details?

Comment: How do you export Autocad files to XML? Are that plan, pool and garden maked as blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-1. Which version of ACAD are you using? CIVIL?

This is the format for CIVIL I believe. 
But I could be wrong I only have Autocad 2011 standard.

see: http://www.landxml.org/

http://www.landxml.org/webapps/landxmlsamples.aspx (samples)

More Info on ACAD XML
See: 
http://images.autodesk.com/latin_am_main/files/2144863_Autodesk_WP_XML-at-Autodesk.pdf
http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/Visual-LISP-AutoLISP-and-General/How-To-Read-Xml-File/td-p/2377688

-2. Basically once you understand the ACAD XML format it's just a matter of searching 
through the XML file (text file)

see: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2719

see: [search and output data from an XML file using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648454/search-and-output-data-from-an-xml-file-using-javascript) (advanced)

-3. Then just use Javascript to parse it into a HTML page. 
Website HTML file right?

```
     <head>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="loadxmldoc.js"></script>    
    </head>    
    <body>    

    <script type="text/javascript">    

    xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("books.xml");    

    x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]    
    y=x.childNodes[0];    
    document.write(y.nodeValue);    

    </script>    
    </body>    
    </html>
```

Please give more details on your start format & end format. :)

This will also help to answer the question.

Comment: Thank you Ben, i will check the links you mentioned and will get back to you.